# Is it safe to use a C++11 range-based for-loop with an rvalue range-init?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach

Suppose I have a function that returns a `std::vector` by value:

```
std::vector<int> buildVector();
```

It would seem natural to iterate over the result using a range-based `for`:

```
for (int i : buildVector()) {
  // ...
}
```

Question: Is it safe to do so?

My reading of the standard (actually, draft [n4431](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf)) suggests that it might not be, though I'm having a hard time believing that the committee failed to allow for this usage. I'm hoping that my reading is incorrect.

Section 6.5.4 defines the range-based `for`:

```
for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
```

with the following desugaring:

```
{
  auto && __range = range-init;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
             __end = end-expr;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin ) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

where `range-init` is just `( expression )`, and at least for class types, `begin-expr` is either `__range.begin()` or `begin(__range)`, etc.

In my `buildVector` example, I think the `range-init` produces a temporary, which the implementation is allowed to destroy immediately after the `__range` reference is bound. This would mean that the `__range` reference might already be dangling by the time `begin-expr` is evaluated.

Certainly, it should always be safe to write this:

```
std::vector<int> notATemporary = buildVector();
for (int i : notATemporary) {
  // ...
}
```

But I'm hoping I don't have to add this to my list of gotchas.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly safe.

From [class.temporary]/4-5:

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression. The first context is when a default constructor is called [...]
>
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is
> bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound **persists
> for the lifetime of the reference** except:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s *ctor-initializer* [...]
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call [...]
> - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement [...]
> - A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* [...]

None of those exceptions apply. The temporary thus persists for the lifetime of the reference, `__range`, which is the entire loop.

Comment: An important gotcha that will bite you if you start playing with ranges eventually: if you write a range adapter, and it is constructed from an rvalue, and you want to be able to chain it in a `for(:)` expression, you need to store your input range *by value*, because reference lifetime extensions is not transitive.  Take `R&&`, store `R`.

Comment: @Yakk Yep, even though [I tried otherwise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990045/temporary-lifetime-in-range-for-expression). In fact, you even answered that one :)

Comment: @yakk Indeed, that was exactly the situation that got me thinking about this.

Comment: Just be careful if you like boost range adaptors, since:

    `for (int i : buildVector() | boost::adaptors::reversed)`
    
is not safe

Comment: Based on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29990971/10301017) I wonder if the justification given here is correct? Range-based for loop seems to have its own rules when it comes to reference liftime extension. In particular: "It seems to be the only part of the standard where a reference is implicitly bound to extend the lifetime of an expressions result without extending the lifetime of nested temporaries."