# Range based for loop on temporary

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-studio-2012, iterator

Consider

```
std::vector<abc> fun() { return a;}
..
..

for( auto itr = fun().begin(); itr< fun().end(); ++itr) //A
 {
  ..
 }
for( auto & itr : fun()) //B
 {
 }
```

Are both loops here are unsafe? (iterators not being compatible?)

Comment: The 2nd version can't work. Both calls to `fun()` returns a different `std::vector<abc>`. You cannot compare iterators from different containers.

Comment: the ranged for you wrote is using vs's extention, it should be const reference

Comment: (I read this questions as you being aware the first variant is wrong.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler It is 100% safe.  You should reread the reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh right, I was confusing it with the case `boost::optional<std::string> f(); ... for (auto c : *(f())) { ... }` which isn't safe because `boost::optional<T>::operator*() &&` returns a `T&&` but the `f()` temporary then isn't lifetime-extended.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined behavior.

```
for( auto itr = fun().begin(); itr< fun().end(); ++itr) //A
{
    ..
}
```

The `std::vector` from `fun().begin()` will be a completely different `std::vector` than that returned from `fun().end()`.

Therefore the comparison `itr < fun().end()` is [comparing iterators from two different containers, which is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657513/comparing-iterators-from-different-containers).

The second version (B) will work fine [as described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448182/is-it-safe-to-use-a-c11-range-based-for-loop-with-an-rvalue-range-init).

```
for (auto & itr : fun()) //B
{
}
```