# Ranged base for loop over temporary reference C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, static, rvalue-reference

I'm wondering if the following is valid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>& getVec()
{
    static std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    for (const auto& i : getVec())
    {
        std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically I'm unsure about the lifetime of the temporary from `getVec()`. I've looked at both [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448182/is-it-safe-to-use-a-c11-range-based-for-loop-with-an-rvalue-range-init) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657708/c11-the-range-based-for-statement-range-init-lifetime), but am in a bit of a different situation as my function returns a reference to `static` data. Specifically, I'm wondering if scenario violates the following exception in the stated rule:

> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call [...]

or if this is indeed safe code. I think it is safe, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: There is no temporary vector here. You are just iterating over `getVec`'s `vec`.

Comment: Ok, I was a bit confused and though maybe the range based for loop was creating a temporary reference to the `vector` returned in `getVec`. Thanks for the clarification. Post an answer if you'd like and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: the range based for loop basically just calls `begin()` and `end()` and exapnds to an iterator based loop. see eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fully valid and well-defined.

The range-based for loop in your question is defined to be equivilent to the following, for imaginary variables `range`, `begin`, and `end`:

```
auto&& range = getVec();
auto begin = std::begin(range);
auto end = std::end(range);
for (; begin != end; ++begin)
{
    const auto& i = *begin;
    {
        std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

After reference collapsing rules are applied, the type of `range` becomes `std::vector<int>&`.  That means no temporaries are ever created.  The loop iterates over the static vector defined in `getVec`.

If `getVec` instead returned by value, the type of `range` would be `std::vector<int>&&`, and lifetime extension would be applied.  That would extend the lifetime of the temporary object to that of the reference, and everything would still be totally valid.